# PDO returning MySQL error with bindParam

Tags: mysql, pdo, php

Hey Guys I'm running this little function here

```
function getBeaches() {

$request=Slim::getInstance()->request();

$args=filter_var_array(func_get_args(),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
$sql="SELECT * FROM beaches WHERE state=:state AND city=:city"; 

    //  var_export($args); die();
    //  array ( 0 => 'wa', 1 => 'seattle', )

try {
    $db         = getConnection();
    $stmt       = $db->prepare($sql);


        $stmt->bindValue('state',   $args[0], PDO::PARAM_STR); //should bind wa 
        $stmt->bindValue('city',    $args[1], PDO::PARAM_STR); //should bind seattle
        $stmt->execute();

    $stmt       = $db->query($sql);
    $beaches    = $stmt->fetchObject();
    $db         = null;

    echo '{"map": ' . stripslashes(json_encode($beaches)) . '}';
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
}

    /* {"error":{"text":SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 
     * 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that  
     * corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
     * near ':state AND city=:city' at line 1}}
     */

}
```

And am getting the error I commented at the bottom, trying to run this like so

`mysql$ SELECT * FROM beaches WHERE state='wa' AND city='seattle';`

May be this rings some bells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You need the semicolons before your param names:</strike> (Not 100% true, see edit)

```
$stmt->bindValue(':state',   $args[0], PDO::PARAM_STR); //should bind wa 
$stmt->bindValue(':city',    $args[1], PDO::PARAM_STR); //should bind seattle
```

From the PHP docs on [PDOStatement::bindValue()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php):

> Parameter identifier. For a prepared statement using named placeholders, this will be a parameter name of the form **:name**. For a prepared statement using question mark placeholders, this will be the 1-indexed position of the parameter.

**EDIT**
As *@jeroen* has pointed out the problem (the same one in your pastebin) that you overwrite the `$stmt` variable before you get the data from it. In you code the problem is around the 17th line:

```
$stmt->execute();  // $stmt now has query results (from the query with parameters bounded)

$stmt       = $db->query($sql); // You redo the query. Now $stmt has no query results and no parameters are bound
$beaches    = $stmt->fetchObject(); // Statement assumes you want to execute query and does so but not parameters are bound
```

You can remedy this by changing the above lines to:

```
$stmt->execute();
$beaches = $stmt->fetchObject();
```

Comment: That's not true, bindParam and bindValue and operate without colons.

Comment: and note they're colons `:` not semicolons `;` ;)

Comment: @ehime It's very true (for your case where you used semicolons). Look at your error for proof. MySQL is receiving `:state AND city=:city` because the values aren't being substituted. Sure you can use another prefix character (such as a `@` or none at all) but that's not what the manual recommends. And whatever you do, the parameter identifier (`$parameter` in the docs) you pass into `bindValue()` must exactly match the one in your string.

Comment: Why is it then, when changing my bindValue to `:$stmt->bindValue(':state', .... $stmt->bindValue(':city',` I receive the same error, and all of my other functions work? http://pastebin.com/r2fy2AGS

Comment: @ehime Because there's an error there too. Since you don't use the semicolon in your `bindValue` the values are inserted into `INSERT INTO sweeps (HERE) VALUES (INSTEAD OF HERE)`. Put a semicolon before the parameter names in all of your `bindValue()`s in that pastebin and it will work properly too.

Comment: It does work properly already and .... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon seriously man...

Comment: Please also let me know why http://pastebin.com/rq7Lmrni dies with the exact error as above, this is literally the most stripped down you can get a PDO statement.

Comment: I meant colons not semicolons. You're splitting hairs on the same token that you are splitting hairs here. Change your code as I suggested in my answer. Let us know if it works.

Comment: There's a problem with: http://pastebin.com/rq7Lmrni. You execute the query with the bound parameter on line 10 and then on line 12 you replaced the `$stmt` (which has the results from the query in it) with a new query and execute this one without binding the value (which is why you get the error again). Try: http://pastebin.com/cTUfhN0J

Comment: @jeroen Yes! I see! Very good catch. Will update answer. Thanks!

Comment: @PhpMyCoder You found it, not me :-)

Comment: @ehime Check updated answer. And previous comment. There was an issue with you calling `PDO::query()` before you retrieved the results with `PDOStatement::fetchObject()`.

Comment: @ehime All of the demos in the manual have the preceding colon, so that would be my recommendation. But as we discovered and you said the problem was the extra `PDO:query()` so as long as the query works  your lack of colons is OK :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but I always used `bindParam` over `bindValue`. If you chose to do so, modify your binders as such:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':state', $args[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':city', $args[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Other than that, everything you're doing looks fine to me.

Comment: I was using `bindParam` first but producing the same error, I was wondering if I wasn't passing by reference so switched to Value, just to check. Same error though =(